# How can I manually create http.IncomingMessage stream?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to manually create http.IncomingMessage stream with some header & body. As it is a readable stream, I can't write/pipe data into it. Is it safe to extend it?

Also, I am not sure how to store headers when it's a stream which doesn't operate on ObjectMode.

**EDIT:**

According to [Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_options_requestlistener), extending http.IncomingMessage is possible.

> IncomingMessage <http.IncomingMessage> Specifies the IncomingMessage class to be used. **Useful for extending the original IncomingMessage.** Default: IncomingMessage.

How can I extend it? Its constructor asks for `Socket` object.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) (you get a badge!) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research, post a [Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and specifically say where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: @Jacob I've already searched, but couldn't find the answer. I didn't add my code attempt because I couldn't any progress. IncomingMessage constructor takes a Socket stream which makes things even more complex.

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve?  Maybe we could better help you directly with that.  `http.IncomingMessage` stream is something that a web server creates for you.  It is not designed to be something you create yourself.  You are free to go study the http server module and see how it creates an `http.IncomingMessage` itself and perhaps you could emulate that, but it is not an API designed for you to use independently.

Comment: @jfriend00 I want to translate custom serverless event into http.IncomingMessage so that existing native server apps continue to work. Also, I want to create dummy http.IncomingMessage for testing.

Answer (score 0):

I mocked it like this in my tests:

```
import { IncomingMessage } from "http";
import { Socket } from "net";

const msg = new IncomingMessage(new Socket());
msg.method = 'POST';
msg.url = "whateverurl"
```

Hope this helps.